# Probability density and mass functions

Tags: probability

What is the maximum value a probability density function and a probability mass function can have? Also, if we take a pdf of a continuous distribution, will the pdf always be continuous? I am a little confused between the physical nature of these functions. I would really appreciate if someone could give an intuitive explanation for these, and how they relate to each other.

Comment: Since probability can't be greater than 1 (an event can have at most a 100% chance of happening), the maximum value either of those functions could possibly take is 1.

Comment: @Dave for pmf yes, for pdf no.

Comment: Pdf is non-negative, measurable, and integrates to $1$. Nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @user251257 what if the pdf was equal to 1 between 0 and 1, and 0 everywhere else?

Comment: @Dave the maximum of a pdf could be any positive number. I don't get your comment.